# How to change the margin top of a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout and I need programmatically to change the top margin of the element. How to change the margin top of a LinearLayout?

Comment: Can you post your layout.?

Answer (score 2):

This way you can set all the 4 margins programmatically.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 40);

ll.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
```

Comment: Don't forget to follow up with `myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the linear layout in layout.xml and want to set the margin of linear layout dynamically you can refer my answer and if you want to create the linear layout also dynamically can refer to @R.J answer.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_menu);
mLayout.setLayoutParams(layout_param);
```